# Does shutil.copy2 (and copytree) could be considered success (files copied are identical) if no exception

Tags: python, shutil, copytree

In a Python project, at some point we copy data with `shutil.copy2` and `shutil.copytree` and we have seen after a while that some files are corrupted, but we are not sure if this is the Python copy or other stuff that corrupted it.

Then the question, since I could not find in shutil documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) a clear statement saying in case of error there is an exception, especially in case of corrupted copy. Anyone knows if there is somewhere this is confirmed?

Comment: `shutil.__file__` returns the path to the source code. You can review that using your favorite editor if you're concerned.

Comment: Thanks @JustinEzequiel for the __file__, I found that at the very end the copy is made with ```with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst``` then basically read fsrc and write to fdst, I'll then look further to it